# How to prevent this error when I type in a blank comment? (Ruby on Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have posts and I allow people to comment on it. The problem is that if someone tries to post a blank comment they get this error message:

```
NameError in Comments#create

Showing app/views/shared/_comment_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined local variable or method `post' for #<#<Class:0x6344a18>:0x635ad20>
```

Extracted source (around line #1):

```
1: <%= form_for([post, @comment]) do |f| %>
2: <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
3:   <div class="field">
4:     <%= f.text_field :comment_content %>
```

Here's what I have in the comment model

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :comment_content

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post

  validates :comment_content, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :post_id, presence: true
```

I thought that the validates :comment_content would prevent anyone from getting any error message from a blank submit, but the above error message comes up.

This is my CommentsController

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
     def new
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
    end

def show
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end

   def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.post = @post
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
       redirect_to(:back)
    else
      render 'shared/_comment_form'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: how `post` variable came here `form_for([post, @comment]`? where it is defined?

Comment: It's defined in the CommentsController. I will update the above with it in a sec

Comment: then it will be `@post` not `post`

Comment: I tried to change it to @post, but I get this message - `NoMethodError in Users#show undefined method `comments_path'` Everything already works fine with my original code and I would like to just prevent an error from coming up when a blank comment is submitted

Comment: Is there a simple validation that I can add that prevents the comment button from going through when it's pressed with an empty comment box?

Comment: your error message and your problem don't match!

Comment: What do you want to do with the "post" variable? You can access your post variable this way: @comment.post. If you want the form to be of action "post", you don't need to define it manually as described here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

Answer (score 0):

since comment_form is a partial, you need to pass a local variable called `post` when you render it otherwise it won't have any knowledge where to get it.

In your controller action, change

```
render 'shared/_comment_form'
```

to

```
render partial: 'shared/_comment_form', locals: { post: @post }
```

I'm not sure if the shortcut for rendering partials will work inside a controller but it's worth a try

```
render 'shared/_comment_form', post: @post
```

Comment: this helps, but I'm getting this error now `Template is missing

Missing partial shared/_comment_form with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :arb, :coffee]}`. Is there a way I can block people from trying to post blank commnets completely?